# Why the php code doesn't write the image?

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a problem with an php app that sends a test result. It should load an image filled with some css, but it doesn't, it tries to load the image, but it doesn't work. It used to work. IDK what happened.

So the app should return something like this:

[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Jjt.png)

from this image

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XafmH.png)

Is the problem in the code below?

Any help please?

```
  foreach($charts as $id=>$chart){

            ?>
                <script>




                    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

                            var isSaved<?php echo $chart['name']; ?>=false;
                            var isImageLoad<?php echo $chart['name']; ?> = false;

                             var imageObj = new Image();
                            imageObj.src = '<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/coaching/roata_vietii/roata2.png';



                            var <?php echo $chart['name']; ?> = document.getElementById("<?php echo $chart['name']; ?>");
                                var <?php echo $chart['name']; ?>Data = {
                                labels: [<?php echo  $labels; ?>],
                                    padding: {
                                        bottom: 900
                                    },
                                datasets: [{
                                    borderWidth: 0,
                                    data: [<?php echo ${$chart['variabila']}; ?>],
                                    backgroundColor: [<?php echo  $backgroundColor; ?> ]
                                }]
                                };

                                var polarAreaChart = new Chart(<?php echo $chart['name']; ?>, {
                                type: 'polarArea',
                                data: <?php echo $chart['name']; ?>Data,
                                responsive:false,
                                options: {

                                    events: [],

                                    layout: {
                                        padding: {
                                          left:70,
                                          right:70,
                                          //top:10,
                                          //bottom:10
                                        },
                                    },
                                    legend: {
                                        display:false,

                                      /*  labels: {
                                            padding:20,
                                            boxWidth:20,
                                            fontSize:15
                                        },*/

                                    },

                                    scale: {
                                            ticks: {
                                                min: 0,
                                                max: 10,
                                                display:false,
                                            },
                                    },

                                    hover: {
                                            animationDuration: 0
                                        },
                                        animation: {

                                            duration: 0,
                                            onComplete: function() {

                                                var chartInstance = this.chart;
                                                var ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                                                var datasets = this.data.datasets;

                                                imageObj.onload = function() {
                                                    if(isSaved<?php echo $chart['name']; ?> == false){
                                                        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
                                                       /* ctx.font = "bolder 15px Arial";
                                                        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                                                        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
                                                        ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
                                                        datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) { 
                                                            var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                                                            meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
                                                                var myangl=((bar._model.startAngle)+(bar._model.endAngle))/2;
                                                            // var xpoint= (parseFloat(bar._model.outerRadius)+20)*(Math.cos(myangl)) + (bar._model.x);
                                                            // var ypoint= (parseFloat(bar._model.outerRadius)+20)*(Math.sin(myangl)) + (bar._model.y);
                                                                var xpoint= (parseFloat(370)+20)*(Math.cos(myangl)) + (bar._model.x);
                                                                var ypoint= (parseFloat(370)+20)*(Math.sin(myangl)) + (bar._model.y);
                                                                ctx.fillText(bar._model.label,xpoint ,ypoint);
                                                            });
                                                        });*/
                                                        isSaved<?php echo $chart['name']; ?> = true;
                                                        jQuery.ajax({
                                                        url: '<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/coaching/roata_vietii/roataVietii-saver.php',
                                                        type: 'POST',
                                                        data: {
                                                            "image" : <?php echo $chart['name']; ?>.toDataURL("image/<?php echo $chart['extension']; ?>"),
                                                            "name" : "<?php echo $chart['name_of_file']; ?>" + ".<?php echo $chart['extension']; ?>",
                                                            "save_location" : "<?php echo $chart['save_location']; ?>" ,
                                                            },
                                                        success: function ()
                                                        {   
                                                            <?php /*if($id !== 1 ){ ?>
                                                                    //if the image is saved, resize the canvas to 100%, for the user
                                                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                                                        var tmpCC = document.getElementById("chart-container<?php echo $chart['name']; ?>");
                                                                        tmpCC.style.backgroundImage = 'url("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/coaching/roata_vietii/images/<?php echo $chart['name_of_file'].".".$chart['extension'];?>")';
                                                                        tmpCC.style.width = "100%";
                                                                        tmpCC.style.height = tmpCC.offsetWidth+"px";
                                                                    },500);
                                                            <?php } */ ?>
                                                        },
                                                        }); 
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: Where did you append `imageObj` to dom?

Comment: http://dontpad.com/phpcodeapp i put the code here. The code is not made by me, i am trying to see where the problem is... but i cannot see it

Comment: In the code, the `imageObj` is never appended anywhere.

Comment: Great,didn't see, Thank you!